# How to detect Help button press in Windows Forms MessageBox?

Tags: winforms, messagebox

I have a message box with 3 buttons: Yes, No, Help:

```
var result = MessageBox.Show("text", "title",
                MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                MessageBoxIcon.Warning,
                MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1,
                true);
```

I can detect if Yes/No buttons where clicked something like this:

```
if(result == DialogResult.Yes)
    // some actions
```

How I can detect that Help button was pressed and execute my own code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to handle the Form's `HelpRequested` event. See the example in [the help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show#System_Windows_Forms_MessageBox_Show_System_String_System_String_System_Windows_Forms_MessageBoxButtons_System_Windows_Forms_MessageBoxIcon_System_Windows_Forms_MessageBoxDefaultButton_System_Windows_Forms_MessageBoxOptions_System_Boolean_).

```
public static DialogResult Show(
    string text,
    string caption,
    MessageBoxButtons buttons,
    MessageBoxIcon icon,
    MessageBoxDefaultButton defaultButton,
    MessageBoxOptions options,
    bool displayHelpButton
)
```